# How to set non-caching SqlParameterSource on JdbcPollingChannelAdapter update parameters

Tags: spring-integration, spring-el

In the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`, I think I understand how to use the `createParameterSourceNoCache()` method of the `ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory` class in order to get a non-caching `SqlParameterSource` object that can be applied to the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`'s select parameters via its `setSelectSqlParameterSource()` method.

However, when it comes to update parameters, I only see it possible to set the update parameters via a `SqlParameterSourceFactory` through the `setUpdateSqlParameterSourceFactory()` method. From what I can tell, it is not possible to set the factory to be non-caching, only to call the non-caching create method of the factory to get a non-caching source object.

I need the update parameter to be the result of a dynamically calculated custom date that changes over time.  I have a static method to dynamically calculate the result, and I was hoping I could use SpEL on the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` to evaluate the update parameter dynamically in the same way that the select parameter can do.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend it and still inject it regular way into the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter`:

```
public class NoCacheExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory 
        extends ExpressionEvaluatingSqlParameterSourceFactory {

    @Override
    public SqlParameterSource createParameterSource(Object input) {
        return createParameterSourceNoCache(input);
    }

}
```

Comment: An exquisite approach, I will get right on it.  Thank you, Artem, as always your responses are great.